# How to delete duplicate rows based on a column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

The table I have is

```
id    user_id    date        created_at
1     123     2020-02-02  2020-02-02 10:00:00
2     123     2020-02-02  2020-02-02 10:00:01
3     789     2020-02-12  2020-02-12 12:00:00
4     456     2020-02-10  2020-02-10 10:00:00
5     456     2020-02-10  2020-02-10 10:00:01
```

I want to delete duplicate entries and I want the desired output -

```
id    user_id    date        created_at
1     123     2020-02-02  2020-02-02 10:00:00
3     789     2020-02-12  2020-02-12 12:00:00
4     456     2020-02-10  2020-02-10 10:00:00
```

I tried the following query -

```
DELETE
    `a`
FROM
    `table1` AS `a`,
    `table1` AS `b`
WHERE
    `a`.`id` < `b`.`id` AND `a`.`user_id` <=> `b`.`user_id`
```

But it's taking too long and the error I get is

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

The table I have has more than 9500000 entries.

What could be a better alternative query?

Comment: What is the criteria which allows to decide what row form a lot rows with the same `user_id` must be stored and what rows must be deleted? least id?

Comment: Yes, the least ID.

Comment: @rik_maz you can check my answer

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep, an then replacing the old table with the new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of records hence it is giving timeout error. Perform this operation in smaller chunk.  Try below query

```
DELETE
        `a`
    FROM
        `table1` AS `a` inner join
        `table1` AS `b`
    WHERE
        `a`.`id` < `b`.`id` AND `a`.`user_id` == `b`.`user_id` and `a`.`id` >***10000(Increase this)***
```

Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use correlated subquery:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table1 t2
               WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                 AND t1.id > t2.id )
```

The index `(user_id, id)` will increase the query speed.